# How to refer to a label?

Tags: nouns, names

I wrote:

> After performing the *extraction command*, (the *Post-Assignments* part / Post-Assignments)  of each rule is / are carried out. Similar to Pre-Assignments, they may update or set some variables in the Vars list.

Each rule consists of some parts which are called, extraction command, pre-assignments, post assignments, etc. I don't know how to treat these names. Can I use for example, *pre-assignments* the way I use *assignments*? or the *extraction command*, the way I use *command*? When to use *part* after them and when to use them as single noun?

Comment: Is there really an "extraction **command**" as such? - I don't fully understand the context, but it seems to me *pre-assignment -> extraction -> post-assignment* are three "subfunctions" always performed consecutively in response to some "data retrieval" command. But yes, you can use *extraction command, pre-assignment, post-assignment* exactly the same as you would use *command, assignment*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, the extraction you point is done according to a command (extraction command) specified in the rule.

Comment: In which case there seems to be some confusion about "the naming of the parts" here. You seem to have a "command" which for argument's sake we could represent as the function call **extract(parameter_list)**. When that "command / function" is executed / called, it performs the subfunctions *pre-assign, extract, post-assign* in sequence. You seem to be saying *extraction* is both the whole sequence of actions *and* one of those actions in particular. As I said, I don't fully understand, but perhaps it would make more sense to refer to *the extraction part* alongside pre/post assignment parts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have a rule like ***if** conditions **then** assignments, extraction command*. *assignments* are divided to *pre-* and *post-assignments*. It is a declarative rule. An extraction function uses such rules for the real extraction and do it int the order you mentioned. It uses the *extraction command* part for doing the extraction.

Answer (score 3):

I would write

> After performing the extraction command, the Post-Assignment part of
>   each rule is carried out.

or

> After performing the extraction command, Post-Assignments of each rule
>   are carried out.

In my experience as a software engineer, either would be acceptable.

Terms like *pre-assignment*, *preassignment*, and *assignment* follow similar English syntax.